# Organic groups, audience filter issue

Tags: 7, organic-groups, views

When adding groups under the 'audience' list box for Organic Groups, i can see ALL groups created by everyone. How can this be limited so the user only see's his/her groups created in the audience list box? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The groups audience field is an entity reference field, which includes a setting to filter the groups using a view. 
So first create a view that lists the logged in users groups, and use that in the groups audience field setting.